# Latency of SSDs versus HDDs

Tags: hard-drive, performance, ssd, latency

We are currently using an HDD for our NetApp storage for our VMs. We're considering replacing them with SSDs, but many disk manufacturers have different performance. What range of latencies can we expect from SSDs versus HDDs? How much better are SSDs on average?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latencies of an SSD vary hugely, but in terms of IOPs (which us probably the term you want to google)you are looking at an increase in the order of 2-5 magnitudes. (Ie 100 iops for HDD, starting at more then 10000 + for an SSD).

Have a look at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOPS

SSDs are like a night and day difference. I would only use hdds for backups and unimportant archival data - like videos, music collections. A heavily swapping HDD can render a system unuseable - while it will just be a bit sluggish on SSD.

Speedwise SSDs are at least 5 times as fast in sequential reads and writes - which represents the closest benchmark

You did not ask, but SSD is also over 5 times as reliable as hdd (but unlike hdd more likely to fail completely and without warning - so RAID is still important)

Comment: If you reread my answer, you will see that I did. SSDs start at 5 times more throughput and go up from there

Comment: another question please , lets say I have HHD disks , and by dmidecode , I get all disks details , can we according to the info from dmidecode find the iops? , if not maybe other linux command ?

Comment: BTW - you said " latencies of an SSD vary hugely" but how it can be while iops is very good and latency is hudely?

Comment: No. DMICode does not tell you about performance or provide particularly detailed info about disks. The only useful information it will provide is about the.motherboard/system model which can tell us something about the sata.controller and what types.of SSDs we can use. Smartctl and hdparm can provide the disk make and model and the iops can be lpoked up in its specs.

Comment: By latencies I assume you mean IOPS (or some derivative thereof). These vary from 10k/sec to over 1m/sec

Comment: ok so when I run Smartctl -a /dev/sdq , then what I need to capture from the output in order to find out the value about iops?

Comment: You get the make and model and then find the specs for it from a datasheet, goigle or the seller.

Comment: since the disks are connected to VM machine , we get "Device does not support Self Test logging" from Smartctl -a

Comment: What does.hdparm -I /dev/sdq output?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something trivial here, but read **latency** (e.g. **time** to fetch what's usually a very small set of bytes) is **not** the same as read **throughput** (typically more sustained bytes / sec). Obviously there are many types of latencies and throughputs one could measure, but when I saw the question asking for _"Latency of SSDs versus HDDs"_, I was expecting an answer on typical differences in read latencies as I defined above in e.g. ms or us, and not so much a discussion of throughput. Don't get me wrong, this is all informative, but it doesn't answer the Q as stated IMHO.

Comment: @josh Im not sure the question as you read it is meaningful - if a hard drive has as the latency as you think if it will be extremely variable depending on HDD caches, block size, fragmentation, location of data on disk etc, while SSD largely eliminates these variables.  In some ways its like asking for the latency of a very small network connection with intermittent congestion - it will vary hugely depending on the queue and what others are doing. IOPS answers the question of latency in this situation by being a proxy for it, allowing an apples to oranges comparison by calling both fruit.

Answer (score 1):

NVMe SSD latencies can be as low as [250 µs](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/nvme-vs-sata-vs-m-2-comparison) (microseconds). Much faster than the typical [2-4 ms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive_performance_characteristics#Rotational_latency) (millisecond) latencies of HDDs that spin at 7,500 - 15,000 RPM.

0.25 ms vs. 2 ms means that an NVMe SSD will have about 1/8th the latency of a fast 15,000 RPM HDD.

However a lot of factors can affect both of these numbers. It is possible for overly-taxed SSDs to provide >1 millisecond performance, and a cache on an HDD could at times provide zippier data access to commonly-used blocks. YMMV and you should consider running your own tests for the disks you are considering deploying.